# Stability of alkenes by hyper conjugation

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability

I have learnt that for carbocations, electrons are delocalized from the $\ce{C-H}$ $\sigma$-bond to the empty p-orbital of carbon.

Moreover, alkenes are stabilized by the delocalization of electron from $\ce{C-H}$ $\sigma$-bond to the empty anti bonding $\pi$ molecular orbital.

But, don't electrons in anti bonding molecular orbitals lead to instability? So, how does hyper conjugation lead to stability of alkenes?

I believe this question has already been asked before, but I couldn't find any satisfactory and/or relevant answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing the *mixing* of orbitals with the *promotion* of electrons from one orbital to another. You're thinking of this:

$\hspace{50 mm}$[image: Promotion of electron]

I don't blame you, because the phrasing "delocalisation into an antibonding orbital" implies that, but that is *not* actually what happens.

In what actually happens, the two original orbitals are said to *mix*. They cease to exist. They overlap to give two new MOs, one which is even lower in energy and one which is higher in energy, like in this diagram:

$\hspace{45 mm}$[image: Mixing]

The "new MO 1" has characteristics of both the original $\ce{C-H}$ $\sigma$ as well as the original $\ce{C=C}$ $\pi^*$, which is why we loosely say "donation into the $\pi^*$ orbital". However, don't take it too literally. **The phrase means that two orbitals are mixed. It does not mean that electrons are promoted from one orbital to another.**

Comment: But still, we are DELOCALIZING electron density into an anti bonding orbital.So, shouldn't that be unstable?

Comment: Wait, which orbital is "lower in energy" ?